# Remove Colouring on Links in LaTeX Template

Tags: colors, latex, hyperref

I am using LaTeX in Overleaf with a template from my university. It has these coloured `\ref` and `\cite` links in the PDF viewer, which I find very annoying. Does anyone know what settings creates these colours (see image below)? I have never seen them before in any of my LaTeX documents.

[image: Image showing green highlighted text]

These are the settings at the top of the page:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Activating style packages
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Settings for referencing (via Natbib)
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ThesisExample.bib}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Graphicx package and hyper referencing
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx} % Handles import graphics
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyper referencing
\usepackage{lscape}   % Landscape positioning pages
\usepackage{url}      % Include url codes
\usepackage{booktabs} % Book quality tables

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Font selection
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{palatino} % Set palatino font
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Idem, but for math environment

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Graphics settings
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.jpg}{bmp}{}{}
\graphicspath{{./}}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Removing indentation, include french (non US) spacing
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%
\newcommand{\mySkip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\mySkip}

\frenchspacing

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Activate tikz and include some specific packages
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes, calc, positioning}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Latex logo (unclear what you need it for)
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{doc}

 
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Blank page
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
 
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
   \vspace*{\fill}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \clearpage
} % end new command
 
 
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Hyper setup
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
 
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {My thesis},
    pdfauthor = {My name},
    pdfsubject = {My topic},
    hidelinks
}
```

Comment: I would check out: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks and https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1193

Comment: Thanks. the first solution didn't work, but one of the ones down in the feed did. I used the following: ```\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in an old feed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks

The following didn't work for me: `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`

What did work was:

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `hyperref` package has an option `colorlinks` that can be used as follows:

```latex
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: @Hans.nl ... then you should add a [mre] to your question which allows us to actually reproduce your problem

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. I found a solution with @CootMoon 's comment, but thanks for the support.